# Django admin - store small pieces of data

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am quite new to django.

I have one problem to solve.

My website has couple of places where i would like to put some content (static text) managed by admin panel.
I know that there is django flatpage or some project like django-chunk. Flatpage has only couple of fields and django-chunk has all in one place (key-value).

I would like to add to panel admin new position only with edit view where user can fill couple of text fields. After save data is storied in file (or in database).

Generally i would like to store small pieces of text like phone number, address, some tagline which are on several pages. And creating model with full CRUD is unnecessary.

How can i do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that creating a model is unnecessary, but not why. I think it is the right way to go.

```
class Snippet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    body = models.TextField()
```

Register it with the admin, and create as many snippets as you need.  You could disable add and delete permissions if you only want your users to be able to edit the ones you've specified.

Add them to the template context:

```
def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(request, *args, **kwargs)
    data['snippet1'] = Snippet.objects.get(name='snippet1').body
    data['snippet2'] = Snippet.objects.get(name='snippet2').body
    return data
```

Then print them in the template:

```
...
Contact us at {{ snippet1 }}!
...
```

This is a bit simplified. You may want a view mixin that adds all the snippets you need based on a declarative list of names, you probably want to optimize the queries so you don't loop through and hit the database 10 times per request, but this is a good start to a simple solution.

Comment: Your way is good. But it would not solve my problem completely. Making it like this will make new row (in database) for each snippet and they all will be listed in one place. I would like to separate snippets for each sub site and let someone only edit them without any list. Just edit form linked from main site of admin panel. Separate link for each site.